# Falha iniciar a API do Jitsi Meet - Erro no lib-jitsi-meet em initJitsiConference (TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of null)

Tags: javascript, api, jitsi

Estou tentando usar a [Jitsi Meet API](https://github.com/jitsi/lib-jitsi-meet/blob/master/doc/API.md) para criar videoconferências com a GUI personalizada e procurei seguir as orientações da [documentação](https://github.com/jitsi/lib-jitsi-meet/blob/master/doc/API.md#getting-started) porém não obtive sucesso, sempre recebo o mesmo erro.

Estou recebendo um `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of null` quando crio o JitsiConference objeto -> `initJitsiConference()`.

**Características do ambiente do servidor:**

- A instalação padrão do Jitsi Meet não foi alterada;
- Não instalei / configurei o plug-in de autenticação de token Prosody JWT;
- Estou executando o aplicativo test.html em um domínio, por exemplo: https://mydomain1.com e Jitsi Meet em outro domínio, por exemplo: https://meet.myotherdomain2.com

**Recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro (console do Chrome):**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Olhando `JitsiConference.js` na linha 276, vejo o seguinte:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Meu javascript da API (mydomain.com/test.html) tem a seguinte aparência:**

```
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://meet.jit.si/libs/lib-jitsi-meet.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
JitsiMeetJS.init();

const options = {
    serviceUrl:'https://meet.jit.si/http-bind',
    hosts: {
        domain: 'meet.jit.si',
        muc: 'conference.meet.jit.si',
    },
    bosh: 'https://meet.jit.si/http-bind',
    useStunTurn: true
}

var connection = new JitsiMeetJS.JitsiConnection(null, null, options);

const confOptions = {
    openBridgeChannel: true
}

room = connection.initJitsiConference("testconference1", confOptions);
</script>
```

**Eu tentei trabalhar com outras instâncias públicas:**

- meet.jit.si
- jitsi2.linux.it
- jitsi-1.belnet.be
- jitsi.riot.im
- de-bra-1.jitsi.rocks
- meet.xrv.pt

E obteve erros semelhantes (console do Chrome):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of null - JitsiConference.js:263 
    at oe.resourceCreator (JitsiConference.js:263)
    at t.value (xmpp.js:461)
    at oe._init (JitsiConference.js:297)
    at new oe (JitsiConference.js:127)
    at c.initJitsiConference (JitsiConnection.js:113)
```

**Arquivo de log (Jicofo.log) encontrei [WARNING] e [SEVERE]**

```
Jicofo 2020-05-15 20:05:23.771 WARNING: [22] org.jitsi.jicofo.FocusManager.log() No dedicated JVB MUC XMPP connection configured - falling back to the default XMPP connection
...
Jicofo 2020-05-15 20:05:24.335 SEVERE: [28] org.jitsi.impl.protocol.xmpp.OpSetSimpleCapsImpl.getFeatures().144 Failed to discover features for speakerstats.meet.myserver.com: XMPP error reply received from speakerstats.meet.myserver.com: XMPPError: service-unavailable - cancel
Jicofo 2020-05-15 20:05:24.337 SEVERE: [28] org.jitsi.impl.protocol.xmpp.OpSetSimpleCapsImpl.getFeatures().144 Failed to discover features for focus.meet.myserver.com: XMPP error reply received from focus.meet.myserver.com: XMPPError: service-unavailable - wait
Jicofo 2020-05-15 20:05:24.345 SEVERE: [28] org.jitsi.impl.protocol.xmpp.OpSetSimpleCapsImpl.getFeatures().144 Failed to discover features for conferenceduration.meet.myserver.com: XMPP error reply received from conferenceduration.meet.myserver.com: XMPPError: service-unavailable - cancel
...
Jicofo 2020-05-15 20:05:29.629 WARNING: [40] org.jitsi.jicofo.bridge.BridgeSelector.log() No pub-sub node mapped for jvbbrewery@internal.auth.meet.myserver.com/2671872e-fccb-49e9-866b-28813c831825
...
Jicofo 2020-05-15 20:05:29.651 INFO: [55] org.jitsi.jicofo.bridge.JvbDoctor.log() Scheduled health-check task for: jvbbrewery@internal.auth.meet.myserver.com/2671872e-fccb-49e9-866b-28813c831825
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.dom4j.io.SAXContentHandler (file:/usr/share/jicofo/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar) to method com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser$LocatorProxy.getEncoding()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.dom4j.io.SAXContentHandler
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

**Arquivo de log (jvb.log) encontrei [WARNING]**

```
2020-05-15 20:05:24.645 WARNING: [22] Videobridge.start#906: No authorized source regexp configured. Will accept requests from any source.
```

Qual erro(s) devo estar cometendo?

Answer (score 0):

Analisando com mais cuidado, concluí que não estava esperando (`addEventListener`) pelo evento CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED e com algumas modificações no código...

Retirei também a opção `bosh: 'https://meet.jit.si/http-bind'` pois parece estar obsoleta.

Incluí as dependências dos javascritps:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/strophe.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/strophejs-plugin-disco/lib/strophe.disco.js?v=1"></script>
```

**Código com as modificações:**

```
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/strophe.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/strophejs-plugin-disco/lib/strophe.disco.js?v=1"></script>
<script src="https://meet.jit.si/libs/lib-jitsi-meet.min.js"></script>
<script>

function onConnectionSuccess(){
    const confOptions = {
        openBridgeChannel: true
    }
    room = connection.initJitsiConference("abcdef", confOptions);
    room.join();
    room.myUserId();
    console.log('CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED');
}

JitsiMeetJS.init();

JitsiMeetJS.setLogLevel(JitsiMeetJS.logLevels.ERROR);

const options = {
    serviceUrl:'https://meet.jit.si/http-bind',
    hosts: {
        domain: 'meet.jit.si',
        muc: 'conference.meet.jit.si',
    }
}

var connection = new JitsiMeetJS.JitsiConnection(null, null, options);

connection.addEventListener(JitsiMeetJS.events.connection.CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED, onConnectionSuccess);

connection.connect();

</script>
```

Veja que na [documentação da API no ítem 4 de "Começando"](https://github.com/jitsi/lib-jitsi-meet/blob/master/doc/API.md#getting-started), a orientação é para aguardar o evento CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED e só então  criar o objeto JitsiConference.
Agora parece que tudo está funcionando corretamente.

Obrigado a todos pelo seu tempo e dedicação.

*P.S.: Sou novo no StackOverflow e estou empenhado ao máximo em dar a melhor resposta que possa ajudar a comunidade.*